# How can I construct this list from this function in R?

Tags: r, list

I have a function `h(n)` that returns values for each integer 1 =< n =< k.

How can I construct a list of the form `(h(1), h(2), h(3), ...)` where k is large so doing this manually will take some time.

Comment: R is a vectorised language, so if you show us your `h` we can help you to take advantage of that, such that typing `h(1:10)` will return `c(h(1), h(2), ..., h(10))`.

Comment: Question as posed is vague and open to (mis)interpretation.  Please provide your function so we can help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your function, I don't know for sure, but `lapply(1:k, h)` should take every value between 1 and k and send it to your function and return them in a list.

```
> h <- function(n) return(1:n)
> lapply(1:5, h)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1 2

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[4]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[5]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

P.S. This isn't homework is it?